# New PHP5.3.10 update error

Tags: 12.04, updates, dpkg, php, awk

After receiving the latest announcement about security vulnerabilities of PHP5 (Ubuntu Security Notice USN-2254-1) I decided to upgrade my server, but I ran into some problems. The new packages listed are:

```
  libapache2-mod-php5             5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12
  php5-cgi                        5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12
  php5-cli                        5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12
  php5-fpm                        5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12
```

But no matter what I do I keep getting these errors. Here is a typical output I get from console:

```
# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up libapache2-mod-php5 (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12) ...
/usr/bin/ucf: line 520: awk: command not found
dpkg: error processing libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up php5-cgi (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12) ...
/usr/bin/ucf: line 520: awk: command not found
dpkg: error processing php5-cgi (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5:
 php5 depends on libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12) | libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12) | php5-cgi (>= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12) | php5-fpm (>= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12); however:
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 is not configured yet.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5filter is not installed.
  Package php5-cgi is not configured yet.
  Package php5-fpm is not installed.
dpkg: error processing php5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up php5-cli (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12) ...
/usr/bin/ucf: line 520: awk: command not found
dpkg: error processing php5-cli (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php5
 php5-cgi
 php5
 php5-cli
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This has never happened before, so assume this is the result of the latest update?

So far I have tried reinstalling packages in different ways, but I always come back to this error list.

UPD.: I am also running into the same error `awk: command not found` with other things...

P.S. The system is Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-64-generic-pae i686)

Comment: It seems that awk isn't installed. try this command: which awk and post output

Comment: It seems it is present `which awk` does not return anything, but this works `# whereis awk`, output: `awk: /usr/bin/awk /usr/share/man/man1/awk.1.gz`

Comment: can you post `echo $PATH` output?

Comment: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

Comment: Also it seems really weird but, when I try to run something simple like this: `awk '{ print }' /etc/passwd` I get output like this `The program 'awk' can be found in the following packages:
 * gawk
 * mawk
 * original-awk`. Then running `mawk '{ print }' /etc/passwd` gives the right output, but I can't understand why doesn't it react to just `awk`...

Comment: And one more. I tried to reconfigure GRUB to start RAID1 and I got stopped with the same error! `awk: command not found`

Comment: can you post `ls -l /usr/bin` output?

Comment: Hmmm... But it is massive... [.pdf with output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yhqlbap35fir8w2/ls_out.pdf)

Comment: can you try `/usr/bin/awk '{print}' /etc/passwd` ?

Comment: It seems that `$PATH` is not inherited by child of your bash process, did you `export $PATH` where you defined `$PATH`?

Comment: `# /usr/bin/awk '{print}' /etc/passwd` gives this... `-bash: /usr/bin/awk: No such file or directory`... IDK, I didn't do anything in particular to setting `$PATH`, I am using default settings of 12.04 LTS.

Comment: My worry is that this is something to do with the latest updates of ubuntu, since I have been running this system and updating it for about a year now and I never had this problem... odd...

Comment: could you post `ls -l /usr/bin/awk` and `update-alternatives --display awk` output? On Ubuntu awk is an alternative link to mawk, I suppose there is a broken alternative link

Comment: Input: `# ls -l /usr/bin/awk`, out: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jan  1 18:56 /usr/bin/awk -> /etc/alternatives/awk`. Then it does in fact seem that the link is broken: in: `update-alternatives --display awk`, out: `awk - auto mode   link currently absent  /usr/bin/mawk - priority 5  slave awk.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/mawk.1.gz  slave nawk: /usr/bin/mawk  slave nawk.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/mawk.1.gz Current 'best' version is '/usr/bin/mawk'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix broken alternatives link for awk try:

```
    sudo update-alternatives --set awk /usr/bin/mawk
```

Verify if it is fix with command:

```
    awk '{print $0}' /etc/passwd
```

Redo apt command:

```
    apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If this doen't work and directory /etc/alternatives doesn't exists, try:

```
    sudo mkdir /etc/alternatives
    sudo update-alternatives --all
```

chose everything to be in 'auto' mode.

Comment: I got this unfortunately: `update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/mawk to provide /usr/bin/awk (awk) in manual mode.
update-alternatives: error: error creating symbolic link '/etc/alternatives/awk.dpkg-tmp': No such file or directory`

Comment: uh! could you post `ls -l /etc/alternatives` output?

Comment: hmm, the `alternatives` directory doesn't exist... it is not on the list in etc and so the output is `ls: cannot access /etc/alternatives: No such file or directory`. should I create it?

Comment: Okey, try: `sudo mkdir /etc/alternatives` and than `sudo update-alternatives --all`

Comment: Yay! It has finally worked! N.B. When I updated alternatives I chose everything to be in 'auto' mode.